# Should I chose k = 3 in this case of KNN classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, knn

I have data with the dimension of (2055, 95). I split it into train data: (1640, 95) and validation data: (415, 95).

I build a KNN classifier but don't know which k param to choose so set k in range and find out which k is fit for my problem. But I got this data:

[image]

[image]

I know that if we choose k = 1 means that the model is overfitting. So in my case, the best k is 3?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is off-topic here.

Comment: Please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

To determine the optimal k parameter in KNN, I would suggest to plot silhouette coefficient for different k values and apply elbow method to determine which one is the most suitable.

```
silhouette_coefficients = []

for k in range(2, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, **kmeans_kwargs)
    kmeans.fit(scaled_features)
    score = silhouette_score(scaled_features, kmeans.labels_)
    silhouette_coefficients.append(score)


plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
    plt.plot(range(2, 11), silhouette_coefficients)
    plt.xticks(range(2, 11))
    plt.xlabel("Number of Clusters")
    plt.ylabel("Silhouette Coefficient")
    plt.show()
```

For such a case below the optimal would be 3 since the rate of change decreases after x=3.

[image]

You can have a look at https://code-ai.mk/kmeans-elbow-method-tutorial/ for further information on elbow method.